# How can I determine if a date is between two dates in Java?

Tags: java, date

How can I check if a date is between two other dates, in the case where all three dates are represented by instances of `java.util.Date`?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

If you don't know the order of the min/max values

```
Date a, b;   // assume these are set to something
Date d;      // the date in question

return a.compareTo(d) * d.compareTo(b) > 0;
```

If you want the range to be inclusive

```
return a.compareTo(d) * d.compareTo(b) >= 0;
```

You can treat `null` as unconstrained with

```
if (a == null) {
    return b == null || d.compareTo(b) < 0;
} else if (b == null) {
    return a.compareTo(d) < 0;
} else {
    return a.compareTo(d) * d.compareTo(b) > 0;
}
```

Comment: Works, but not readable. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @BrunoDeFreitasBarros What do you mean by "not readable"?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Bruno means it's hard to understand code w/o comment.

Comment: if (d == a || d == b)  it's not work.

Comment: @junsid for inclusive range I have added an update.  Thank you.

Comment: How can i handle null to & from date?

Comment: @saran3h I have added an example handling `null` values for `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 291):

This might be a bit more readable:

```
Date min, max;   // assume these are set to something
Date d;          // the date in question

return d.after(min) && d.before(max);
```

Comment: A very healthy 9 seconds faster, sir.

Comment: between can include the endpoints, in which case you could use return !d.before(min) && !d.after(max);

Comment: @Tetsujin no Oni sorry man, its a good thing I don't have a big deliverable due in a couple weeks that is both helped and hurt by SO. :)

Comment: @PatrickMcDonald you can write this other way too: !(d.before(min) || d.after(max))

Comment: @NathanFeger, one more point I want to the `after()` and `before()` both are exclude type which means `after()` doesn't give the result for of `d` day, I have same scenario where I have to include `min` and `max` date in report by `if((date.after(fromDate) || date.compareTo(fromDate)==0) && (date.before(toDate) || date.compareTo(toDate)==0 ))` it doesn't give any result. Please suggest good approach

Comment: Is this better than the "selected solved answer"?

Comment: @ChristianMoen yes. However I'm not sure if java 8 changes this, I'm a little rusty now.

Answer (score 50):

Like so:

```
Date min, max;   // assume these are set to something
Date d;          // the date in question

return d.compareTo(min) >= 0 && d.compareTo(max) <= 0;
```

You can use `>` instead of `>=` and `<` instead of `<=` to exclude the endpoints from the sense of "between."

Comment: Thanks for your immediate Response.

Comment: This doesn't always work. I have had problems using compareTo on Date objects. Jan 1 2006 was apparently after Apr 1 2006 in one of my programs.

Comment: @KitsuneYMG: I tried the following code and is working as expected: `Date date1 = new Date(2006, 1, 1); // Jan 1,2006 Date date2 = new Date(2006, 4, 1); // Apr 1, 2006 System.out.println(date1.compareTo(date2)); // -1 System.out.println(date2.compareTo(date1)); // 1`.  Can you share here what is that *not working* for you?

Comment: This is the **exact** Answer for `between`. Others are for `within` the date.

Answer (score 17):

Between dates Including end points can be written as

```
public static boolean isDateInBetweenIncludingEndPoints(final Date min, final Date max, final Date date){
    return !(date.before(min) || date.after(max));
}
```

NB: as @Ponmudi pointed out in the comments, this solution may not work if the dates are different at miilliseconds level.

Comment: Note that after() and before() may not work as expected when date matches.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52246234/why-does-javas-date-after-return-true-when-the-date-is-actually-earlier

Comment: how can I use this inside a java8 filter

Answer (score 12):

Here's a couple ways to do this using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library.

One way is to use the simple `isBefore` and `isAfter` methods on [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) instances. By the way, DateTime in Joda-Time is similar in concept to a java.util.Date (a moment in time on the timeline of the Universe) but includes a time zone.

Another way is to build an Interval in Joda-Time. The `contains` method tests if a given DateTime occurs within the span of time covered by the Interval. The beginning of the Interval is inclusive, but the endpoint is exclusive. This approach is known as "Half-Open", symbolically `[)`.

See both ways in the following code example.

Convert the java.util.Date instances to Joda-Time [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) instances. Simply pass the Date instance to constructor of DateTime. In practice you should also pass a specific [`DateTimeZone`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html) object rather than rely on JVM’s default time zone.

```
DateTime dateTime1 = new DateTime( new java.util.Date() ).minusWeeks( 1 );
DateTime dateTime2 = new DateTime( new java.util.Date() );
DateTime dateTime3 = new DateTime( new java.util.Date() ).plusWeeks( 1 );
```

Compare by testing for before/after…

```
boolean is1After2 = dateTime1.isAfter( dateTime2 );
boolean is2Before3 = dateTime2.isBefore( dateTime3 );

boolean is2Between1And3 = ( ( dateTime2.isAfter( dateTime1 ) ) && ( dateTime2.isBefore( dateTime3 ) ) );
```

Using the Interval approach instead of isAfter/isBefore…

```
Interval interval = new Interval( dateTime1, dateTime3 );
boolean intervalContainsDateTime2 = interval.contains( dateTime2 );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "DateTimes: " + dateTime1 + " " + dateTime1 + " " + dateTime1 );
System.out.println( "is1After2 " + is1After2 );
System.out.println( "is2Before3 " + is2Before3 );
System.out.println( "is2Between1And3 " + is2Between1And3 );
System.out.println( "intervalContainsDateTime2 " + intervalContainsDateTime2 );
```

When run…

```
DateTimes: 2014-01-22T20:26:14.955-08:00 2014-01-22T20:26:14.955-08:00 2014-01-22T20:26:14.955-08:00
is1After2 false
is2Before3 true
is2Between1And3 true
intervalContainsDateTime2 true
```

Answer (score 10):

Another option

```
min.getTime() <= d.getTime() && d.getTime() <= max.getTime()
```

Comment: This is the only optimal solution, the rest seem overcomplicated for something simple.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

        String oeStartDateStr = "04/01/";
        String oeEndDateStr = "11/14/";

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Integer year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        oeStartDateStr = oeStartDateStr.concat(year.toString());
        oeEndDateStr = oeEndDateStr.concat(year.toString());

        Date startDate = sdf.parse(oeStartDateStr);
        Date endDate = sdf.parse(oeEndDateStr);
        Date d = new Date();
        String currDt = sdf.format(d);


        if((d.after(startDate) && (d.before(endDate))) || (currDt.equals(sdf.format(startDate)) ||currDt.equals(sdf.format(endDate)))){
            System.out.println("Date is between 1st april to 14th nov...");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Date is not between 1st april to 14th nov...");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `getTime()` and compare the returned long UTC values.

EDIT if you are sure you'll not have to deal with dates before 1970, not sure how it will behave in that case.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) which is a really good API for dealing with date/time. Even though if you don't really need it for the solution to your current question it is bound to save you pain in the future.

Comment: Yes my immediate thought was to suggest Joda time but I can't see anything in the API to support a "within range" test. Anyone else?

Comment: I am not suggesting Joda for this particular problem, since it already has numerous solutions.

Comment: But you would create an Interval in Joda Time to do this

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Date;

public class IsDateBetween {

public static void main (String[] args) {

          IsDateBetween idb=new IsDateBetween("12/05/2010"); // passing your Date
 }
 public IsDateBetween(String dd) {

       long  from=Date.parse("01/01/2000");  // From some date

       long to=Date.parse("12/12/2010");     // To Some Date

       long check=Date.parse(dd);

       int x=0;

      if((check-from)>0 && (to-check)>0)
      {
             x=1;
      }

 System.out.println ("From Date is greater Than  ToDate : "+x);
}   

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to find whether today is between 2 months:

```
private boolean isTodayBetween(int from, int to) {
    if (from < 0 || to < 0 || from > Calendar.DECEMBER || to > Calendar.DECEMBER) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid month provided: from = " + from + " to = " + to);
    }
    Date now = new Date();
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.setTime(now);
    int thisMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    if (from > to) {
        to = to + Calendar.DECEMBER;
        thisMonth = thisMonth + Calendar.DECEMBER;
    }
    if (thisMonth >= from && thisMonth <= to) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and call it like:

```
isTodayBetween(Calendar.OCTOBER, Calendar.MARCH)
```