# How to check if a day lies between a range?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, calendar, dayofweek

I have a job which runs from a given day to a certain day of week . For eg (Monday to Saturday).
I was able to cover the case when stopday > starday for eg-startday->Monday stopDay->Saturday
but when the range changes to something like Wednesday to Monday , I am not able to cover this case.

```
private boolean isNotWindow(DateTime todayDate) {
        final int hr = 3600;
        final int min = 60;
        int stopDay =
                Integer.parseInt(ShipmentTrackingEmailProperties.getInstance().getProperty(
                        ShipmentTrackingEmailProperties.SHIPMENT_EMAIL_STOP_DAY));
        int startDay =
                Integer.parseInt(ShipmentTrackingEmailProperties.getInstance().getProperty(
                        ShipmentTrackingEmailProperties.SHIPMENT_EMAIL_START_DAY));

        if(stopDay<startDay)
        {
            //Not able to figure out??????
        }
        if (todayDate.getDayOfWeek() >= stopDay) {
            String stopTime =
                    ShipmentTrackingEmailProperties.getInstance().getProperty(ShipmentTrackingEmailProperties.SHIPMENT_EMAIL_STOP_TIME);
            String[] array = stopTime.split(":");
            System.out.println(array[0] + "  " + array[1] + "   " + array[2]);
            int hh = Integer.parseInt(array[0]);
            int mm = Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
            int ss = Integer.parseInt(array[2]);
            int tSec = todayDate.getHourOfDay() * hr + todayDate.getMinuteOfDay() * min + todayDate.getSecondOfDay();
            int sSec = hh * hr + mm * min + ss;
            if (tSec > sSec) {
                     return true;
            }
        }
        if (todayDate.getDayOfWeek() <= startDay) {
            String startTime =
                    ShipmentTrackingEmailProperties.getInstance().getProperty(ShipmentTrackingEmailProperties.SHIPMENT_EMAIL_START_TIME);
            String[] array = startTime.split(":");
            int hh = Integer.parseInt(array[0]);
            int mm = Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
            int ss = Integer.parseInt(array[2]);
            int tSec = todayDate.getHourOfDay() * hr + todayDate.getMinuteOfDay() * min + todayDate.getSecondOfDay();
            int sSec = hh * hr + mm * min + ss;
            if (tSec <= sSec) {
                LOG.info("Not a valid day to send mail ." + todayDate.getDayOfWeek());
                 return true;
            }
        }
             LOG.info("Valid day to send mail ." + todayDate.getDayOfWeek());
         return false;
    }
```

This function returns true if the day does not fall in a range.So how to cover the case when
stopDay < startDay

Comment: I have not look at your code. But, I suggest that you try a joda time API. I have a many easy to use functions for date related tasks. Chenqui.

Comment: Is using `JodaTime` an option? If so, you can define an `Interval` and check if it contains your date.

Comment: Here is a SO post which tell us how you do with a Joda - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883060/how-can-i-determine-if-a-date-is-between-two-dates-in-java It is a very easy.

Comment: Date manipulations are fine . But how to work with days and time and check if a certain day,time falls between a range.

Comment: All those functions are for date checking. I want to check if for eg . Saturday falls b/w a range of Wednesday to Monday

Comment: @RamanSingh - I make wrong choice of words. It have a much more functionality than the standard Java Date API. See link, try and let us know.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev - I think you understood the question wrong . I have a DAY (day of a week) and a time and i want to find out if it lies b/w two given DAYOFWEEK and TIME.

Comment: What is todayDate ? Joda DateTime?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev the op already uses joda it seems...

Comment: yeah todayDate is DateTime Object from JODA Api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
if startday<stopday then
    if the day is in the interval (startday,stopday) then OK
    else NotOk
else 
    if the day is not in the interval (startday,stopday) then OK
    else NotOk
```

It could be much easier done as:

```
If((day-startday)*(stopday-day)*(stopday-startday)>=0) then OK
else NotOk
```

Comment: The only thing I added was I had to take in account the time also So I calculated seconds in a days as (dayOfWeek-1)*24*3600 + no. of seconds  and compared them instead of day.

Comment: @RamanSingh Of course. I only wanted to show the main thought... I love logic, based on counting :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to check for the day in range

```
private static boolean inRange(int startDay, int stopDay, int checkMe) {
    if(startDay==stopDay) {
           if(startDay==checkMe){
                   return true;
           } else {
                   return false;
           }
    }
    while(startDay!=stopDay) {
        if(startDay==checkMe || stopDay==checkMe) {
            return true;
        }
        if(startDay==7) {
            startDay =0;
        }
        startDay++;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's correct sir, but could you suggest edit in my code . That will be helpful. Thanks..

Comment: You can use the inRange function to find out if your day is in startday and stopday range. If it falls in day range than you can calculate start time and end time and see if todayDate's time falls in that range or not.