# Check that date is within a given range of date inclusive

Tags: java, date, range

**This question is to compare dates inclusively in Java.**

Is there a better way to check if a given date is within a range inclusively?

```
Date startDate, endDate, dateToCheck;

if ( dateToCheck.equals(startDate) || 
     dateToCheck.equals(endDate) || 
    (dateToCheck.after(startDate) && dateToCheck.before(endDate) )
```

Comment: There are already numerous similar questions here - e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883060/how-can-i-determine-if-a-date-is-between-two-dates-in-java

Comment: Search Stack Overflow before posting.

Comment: @BasilBourque your duplicate is for php...

Answer (score 13):

You can avoid the `equals` checks by checking that the given date is not before or after the range :

```
if (!dateToCheck.before (startDate) && !dateToCheck.after (endDate))
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Joda DateTime there is a specific method you can use from the Interval class: `interval.contains(date)`. You can convert your Java date very easy to the Joda Interval and DateTime.

See [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) for more informations about the contains method.

Edit saw your edit just now (I assume that you are using Java Date):

`Interval interval = new Interval(startDate.getTime(), endDate.getTime());
interval.contains(dateToCheck.getTime());`

Comment: Thank you for answer this is for `java.util.Date`

Answer (score 5):

You can always use the compareTo method for inclusive date ranges:

```
public boolean checkBetween(Date dateToCheck, Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    return dateToCheck.compareTo(startDate) >= 0 && dateToCheck.compareTo(endDate) <=0;
}
```