# Why does Java's Date.after() return 'true' when the date is actually earlier?

Tags: java, date, datetime, jdbc, language-lawyer

I had a program where I compared two dates with each other; even though `date1` was before `date2`, `date1.after(date2)` returned `true`. Time zones had no effect; both dates were in UTC.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        Date date1 = dateFormat.parse("2018-07-27 01:22:14.077");
        Date date2 = new Timestamp(1532654534390l);
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date1));
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date2));
        System.out.println(date1.getTime() > date2.getTime());
        System.out.println(date1.after(date2));
    }
}
```

This outputs:

> 2018-07-27 01:22:14.077
>   2018-07-27 01:22:14.390
>   false
>   true

What is happening here?

---

<sub>In my real program, `date1` is parsed from a log file and `date2` is retrieved from the database by Hibernate, which causes the different data types. Even though I found the root cause and know how to avoid the problem, I'm still very interested in solutions which prevent this pitfall.</sub>

Comment: **Read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html)**. It warns you against treating a `Timestamp` as a `Date`, predicts the behavior you saw, and explains why. No news here.

Comment: @BasilBourque right, but in the real program I'm defining `date2` as a `java.util.Date` and Hibernate returns me a `java.sql.Timestamp`. I haven't noticed that for 6-8 years I'm working on this application until now.

Comment: That is why this class design hack is so insidious, the compiler is unaware and unable to enforce their pretend-Timestamp-is-not-Date policy. Fortunately Hibernate supports *java.time*, to help end the long nightmare of `Date`/`Calendar`/`Timestamp`.

Comment: When I redesign the application, I will for sure take that into account. Still, other people might be stuck with Java 7 for whatever reasons.

Comment: If you need operations like these in Java 7, consider [the ThreeTen Backport library](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of java.time to Java 6 and 7.

Comment: As an aside, avoid lowercase `l` for long literals, it’s hard to distinguish from digit 1. I recommend `1_532_654_534_390L` for readability (unfortunately an underscore is not allowed between the last digit and the `L`).

Comment: @OleV.V. I don't use these literals in the real application, this is just an MCVE :) I see Basil and you using underscores, that's a nice trick.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The underlying 'problem' here is that [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html), while extending [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), doesn't store milliseconds in the designated field (`fastTime`, equivalent to [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)), but in a separate field `nanos`. The [`after`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after-java.util.Date-) method only considers the `fastTime` field (which makes sense, since it can be used on all `Date` objects).

What happens in this situation is that the `fastTime` of the `Timestamp` is *rounded down* from 1532654534**390** to 1532654534**000**, which is lower than the 1532654534**077** of the other date (and lower means an earlier date). Therefore, `after()` and `before()` are not reliable in this case; the solution is to use `getTime()` (which is overloaded for `Timestamp` to provide the correct value) on both dates and compare those.

Comment: Ideally, you should be using `java.time` API anyway

Answer (score 7):

## tl;dr

Use modern *java.time* classes, never terrible legacy date-time classes.

```
Instant
.ofEpochMilli( 1_532_654_534_390L ) 
.isAfter(
    LocalDateTime
    .parse( 
        "2018-07-27 01:22:14.077"
        .replace( " " , "T" ) 
    )
    .atOffset( 
        ZoneOffset.UTC
    )
    .toInstant()
)
```

## Doc says: Don’t  use `Timestamp` object as `Date`

Your code:

```
Date date2 = new Timestamp…  // Violates class documentation.
```

…violates the contract established in the class documentation.

> Due to the differences between the Timestamp class and the java.util.Date class mentioned above, it is recommended that code not view Timestamp values generically as an instance of java.util.Date. The inheritance relationship between Timestamp and java.util.Date really denotes implementation inheritance, and not type inheritance.

The doc notes that while `java.sql.Timestamp` technically inherits from `java.util.Date`, you are instructed to ignore that fact of inheritance. You are not to use `Timestamp` object as a `Date`. Your code is doing exactly what the doc told you *not* to do.

Of course this pretend-it-is-not-a-subclass policy is a ridiculously bad class design. This hack is one of *many* reasons to **never use these classes**.

The behavior you saw, regarding mismatch of milliseconds fractional-second and nanoseconds, is documented:

> Note: This type is a composite of a java.util.Date and a separate nanoseconds value. Only integral seconds are stored in the java.util.Date component. The fractional seconds - the nanos - are separate. The Timestamp.equals(Object) method never returns true when passed an object that isn't an instance of java.sql.Timestamp, because the nanos component of a date is unknown. As a result, the Timestamp.equals(Object) method is not symmetric with respect to the java.util.Date.equals(Object) method. Also, the hashCode method uses the underlying java.util.Date implementation and therefore does not include nanos in its computation.

## java.time

You are using notoriously terrible classes. The problem you found is due to their awful design that used bad hacks. Do not bother trying to understand these classes; just **avoid them entirely**.

These legacy classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

Parse your input string.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2018-07-27 01:22:14.077".replace( " " , "T" ) ;  // Without a time zone or offset, this value has no specific meaning, is *not* a point on the timeline.
```

Apparently you know for a fact that input string was implicitly representing a moment in UTC.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;  // Assign an offset-from-UTC to give the date and time a meaning as an actual point on the timeline.
```

Parse the other input, apparently a count of milliseconds since the first moment of 1970 in UTC. The `Instant` class is more basic than `OffsetDateTime`, a moment in UTC, always UTC by definition.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_532_654_534_390L ) ;  // Translate a count of milliseconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z into a moment on the timeline in UTC.
```

Compare.

```
Boolean stringIsAfterLong = odt.toInstant().isAfter( instant ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).