# SimpleDateFormatting in Java

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

I have a set of helper methods that am currently using to format a date received from an API.

```
public static String ParseDate (String dateR) {
    SimpleDateFormat full_date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);

    try {
        full_date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        Date date = full_date.parse(dateR);

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(date);
        String day = GetDay(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
        int hr = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        return day + ", " +  hr+ ":"  + min;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error" + e);
    }
    return dateR;
}

private static String GetDay(int d)
{
    switch (d)
    {
        case 1:
            return "Sunday";
        case 2:
            return "Monday";
        case 3:
            return "Tuesday";
        case 4:
            return "Wednesday";
        case 5:
            return "Thursday";
        case 6:
            return "Friday";
        case  7:
            return "Saturday";
        default:
            return "";

    }
}
```

I am calling these like this:

```
String str = "2013-09-11T12:50:00Z";
    System.out.println(ParseDate(str));
```

It works perfectly. However, I would like to improve its functionality. 
If the day of the week is not this current week, I would like to show the date rather than showing the day of the week. It would be wrong to show day of week when it is not a day from the current week.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

[UPDATE]:

> For example:
>   When date is : `2013-09-11T12:50:00Z`
>   I get this output: `Wednesday, 18:20`
>   This is wrong. A simple `date` like `24th May, 2013` will be better in this case.

This means that I need to be able to test whether the date falls in this week or exceeds then, should the format the date based on that. I hope am clear:)

Comment: please abbreviate with an `example` . Your question is not Cleared actually @Clinton

Comment: I thought this was an example:

String str = "2013-09-11T12:50:00Z";
    System.out.println(ParseDate(str));

Comment: I am not sure I understood. However, a nice improvement to your code would be replacing the numbers of the switch cases with the Calendar constants (e.g., replace 1 with Calendar.SUNDAY, 2 with Calendar.MONDAY, and so on).

Comment: Ok thanks, and I have updated with an example :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313797/how-to-check-a-day-is-in-the-current-week-in-java check this link.Should help you fix

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Calendar cNow = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
```

Instead of

```
    return day + ", " +  hr+ ":"  + min;
```

use

```
SimpleDateFormat humanDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E, HH:mm", Locale.US);
return (cNow.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) == c.getCalendar(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) ?
    humanDateFormat : full_date).format(c);
```

Comment: Be aware that `Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR` varies by `Locale`. That is, that class’ definition of a week varies, both the starting day (Sunday vs Monday etc.) and what marks week number 1. This vary-by-Locale may be good or bad depending on your needs. Best to always specify your desired/intended Locale rather then rely implicitly on the JVM’s current default locale.

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes now outmoded by the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later. For Java 6 & 7 use the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. For Android, the adaptation of that project, [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). Avoid using the old classes; they really are that bad.

## ISO 8601

Your input string complies with the ISO 8601 standard. The java.time classes use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats by default when parsing/generating textual representations of date-time values. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

## `Instant`

An `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2013-09-11T12:50:00Z" );
```

## Week Number

A week only makes sense in the context of a time zone, so we apply a time zone to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

Get the week number using the [ISO 8601 standard definition of a week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) (week # 1 is first Thursday of Calendar year, running Monday-Sunday).

```
int weekNumberThen = zdt.get ( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR );
int weekNumberNow = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId ).get( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR );
```

## Generate textual representation of date-time value

Finish up your business logic by testing for equality of the two week numbers. Note how we use the handy `DayOfWeek` enum to automatically localize to a display name for day of week. And note how we switch to `LocalDate` for format your date-only value output.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH; // Or Locale.US, and so on.
String output = null;
if( weekNumberThen == weekNumberNow ) {
    DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = zdt.getDayOfWeek();
    output = dayOfWeek.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , locale );
} else {
    LocalDate localDate = zdt.toLocalDate();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( locale );
    output = localDate.format( formatter );
}
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your code . I think you just copy paste this code from some other Sources and didn't understand the Code.

As per your `code` The `output` giving to you is fine.

```
 String day = GetDay(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)); // this will return Day (Wednesday).

int hr = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);  //return Hour of Date (18 in Your Case)

int min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);(Return Minutes ) (20 in Your Case)

return day + ", " +  hr+ ":"  + min; // return "Wednesday, 18:20"
```

So, Final Result what you get from Your method will be `Wednesday, 18:20`.

Just Change the above code will get your Answer.

```
int year = currentCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
String month = currentCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = currentCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
 return day + "th " + month + " "  + year ; // return "24th February ,1991"
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you ask for day of month would help?

```
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Then you can format as String like:

```
String currentDate = String.format("%d %s %d", day, monthName, year);
```

The result would be not "Wednesday", but 24.

The full date formatter could be:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
String monthName = null;
switch (month){
       case 0: monthName = "January"; break;
       case 1: monthName = "February"; break;
       case 2: monthName = "March"; break;
       case 3: monthName = "April"; break;
       case 4: monthName = "May"; break;
       case 5: monthName = "June"; break;
       case 6: monthName = "July"; break;
       case 7: monthName = "August"; break;
       case 8: monthName = "September"; break;
       case 9: monthName = "October"; break;
       case 10: monthName = "November"; break;
       case 11: monthName = "December"; break;
       default: break;
       }
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
String currentDate = String.format("%d %s %d", day, monthName, year);
```