# If else statement

Tags: java, if-statement

Want to have this code to search for dates between 1950-2050 and find out when Nothing happened, World cup, Olympic games or the info you write does not match any of the dates.

So the OL occurs when the number between 1950-2050 is divided by 4. And the WC occurs between even years of the OL like 2002(2004 WC)2006.

Then we have the dates no OL/WC occur between 1950-2050, that year nothing happened. And last if you put in like 700 it should just say the last else.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Write year between 1950-2050: ");
int keyboard = input.nextInt();
int OL = (keyboard);
int WC = (keyboard);
int nothingspec = (keyboard);
int instru = (keyboard);

if(nothingspec) {

 System.out.println("This year nothing special happened.");

}

else if(OL) { 

 System.out.println("Yes this year it the olympic games. ");

}      

else if(WC) { 

    System.out.println("Yes this year it was a world cup in soccer.");

}     

else(instru) {

    System.out.println("Your instructions were wrong please try again.");
}

input.close();
```

Comment: What is the question and what u needed????????????????????

Comment: At-current state your code doesn't compile.

Comment: That title doesn't help either. Seriously, what's the problem?

Comment: Well I know it does not compile, because I have no clue where to start even. I mean how do I actually search for dates with if/else function.

Comment: I will just remove this question and continue to try solving it.

Comment: Did you get an error? and can you show it to us?

Comment: The if statements are looking for a boolean. You set your values as an integer.

Comment: This may help you with your search between dates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494180/java-how-do-i-check-if-a-date-is-within-a-certain-range

Comment: It is not that easy to write a question first being a total noob in java and second english not being my native language. Thank you all for the info and I am really sorry if I confused any of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as i understand it should be something like this

```
         System.out.println("Write year between 1950-2050: ");
         int keyboard = input.nextInt();
         int OL = (keyboard);
         int WC = (keyboard);
         int nothingspec = (keyboard);
         int instru = (keyboard);
         boolean blOL = false;
         boolean blWC = false;
         //this occurs whenever the number can be divided by 4
         if(keyboard>=1950&&keyboard<=2050){
            if(OL%4==0) { 

             System.out.println("Yes this year it the olympic games. ");
            blOL=true;
            }      
            //This will happen every time the date can be divided to 2 so as               you said 2002, 2004, 2006 and so on. 
            else if(WC%2==0) { 

                System.out.println("Yes this year it was a world cup in   soccer.");
            blWC = true;
            }
            //This is when nothing has happend.     
            else if(blOL==false && blWC==false) {

             System.out.println("This year nothing special happened.");

            }
            else{

                System.out.println("Your instructions were wrong please try again.");
            }
          }
          else{

                System.out.println("Your instructions were wrong please try again.");
            }


    input.close();
```

Please try this and tell me if this is what you needed.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfect.

Comment: Greate! Glad i could help