# Test if Unix time-stamp is today in Java 7

Tags: java, unix, timestamp, epoch, date-comparison

I need to check if a Unix time-stamp (stored as a `long`) represents today (in my time zone). This is where I am at, but it doesn't seem very elegant:

```
Calendar tokenTimestamp = Calendar.getInstance();
tokenTimestamp.setTimeInMillis(foo.getDateTimeCreated());

Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

if (tokenTimestamp.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) != now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        || tokenTimestamp.get(Calendar.MONTH) != now.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        || tokenTimestamp.get(Calendar.YEAR) != now.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
    // Not today...
}
```

Is there a more correct and/or elegant way to do this?

Comment: Do you have to use `java.util.Calendar` rather than the `java.time` API? The latter would be considerably simpler...

Comment: I'm on Android so would have to be Java 7.

Comment: This is about codereview and should be ask at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Simply put: no, there is no better way.  You’re doing it the best way it can be done in Java 7.

Comment: Beg to differ, @VGR. There are more than one way I would consider better.

Comment: First off, “today” is a time zone dependent concept, so it would be better to give an explicit time zone to the operation so the reader is reminded that the time zone matters and knows which time zone you intended (rather than thinking you may have forgot to give one).

Comment: @OleV.V. Good point.  Timezone differences can definitely corrupt the result.  (I’ve actually seen that happen in commercially deployed applications.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java 7's `Calendar`, that's probably the best you can do. I'd add just a little detail, specify in what timezone you want the date (as pointed by [@Ole V.V.'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44762934/test-if-unix-time-stamp-is-today-in-java-7#comment76512258_44762934)):

```
// current date in system default timezone
Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
// current date in Europe/London timezone
Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
```

Also use [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Continent/City`, like `America/Sao_Paulo` or `Europe/Berlin`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CST` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231).

---

The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api), and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

For Android you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes, together with the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

All the classes below are under the `org.threeten.bp` package. As you're comparing just the date (day/month/year), I'm using the `org.threeten.bp.LocalDate` class. I also use `org.threeten.bp.ZoneId` to specify the timezone and the `org.threeten.bp.Instant` class to convert the `long` millis value to a date:

```
// millis value
long millis = 1498499869249L;

// get the date in system default timezone
LocalDate dt = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
// check if it's equals to today
System.out.println(dt.equals(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())));
```

If you want a different timezone, replace `ZoneId.systemDefault()` by `ZoneId.of("Europe/London")` (or whatever timezone name you want - you can get a 
list of all available timezones by calling `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`).

And don't forget to use the same timezone in both lines, to make sure you're comparing the correct values.

---

If you want to compare the date and time (day/month/year and hour/minute/second), you can use a `org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime` instead:

```
// get the date in system default timezone
LocalDateTime dt = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
// check if it's equals to today
System.out.println(dt.equals(LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())));
```

Comment: Good answer. In all the snippets I would want to store the time zone (either `TimeZone` or `ZoneId`) in a variable to make quite sure I use the same zone every time even if someone changes the default underway. Just to guard against this unlikely but potentially nasty corner case.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the approach from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494180/java-how-do-i-check-if-a-date-is-within-a-certain-range): You define a start date (today, at 0am) and an end date (today, 23:59pm).
Then you can check if the time is in between with:

```
boolean isWithinToday(Date testDate) {
   return !(testDate.before(startTime) || testDate.after(endTime));
}
```