# Is there a java class that represent a range between two instants?

Tags: java, java-time

I do want to check if an Instant is between two other instants:

Currently I use:

```java
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.Instant;

Instant start = Instant.from(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.parse("2016-10-25T12:31:39.084726218Z"));
Instant end = Instant.from(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.parse("2016-10-25T13:31:39.084726218Z"));


// for exclusive range 
Instant testSubject1 = Instant.from(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.parse("2016-10-25T12:31:40Z"));
boolean isInRange1 = testSubject1.isAfter(start) && testSubject1.isBefore(end); // this works as exclusive range

//for inclusive range
Instant testSubject2 = Instant.from(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.parse("2016-10-25T12:31:39.084726218Z"));
boolean isInRange2 = (testSubject2.equals(start) || testSubject2.isAfter(start)) && (testSubject2.equals(end) || testSubject2.isBefore(end)); // inclusive range
```

Is there any other utility function is the standard library or elsewhere that allows for this kind of range check is a simplified way?

I'm looking for something like:

```java
new InstantRange(start,end).checkInstantWithin(testSubject1); 

// or

InstantUtils.inRangeExclusive(start,end, testSubject1);
InstantUtils.inRangeInclusivestart,end, testSubject1);
```

Comment: I don't think there is. This seems to me both too trivial to do, and too depending on the use-cases every different programmers will identifies, to be a great candidate for providing it along with the language.

Comment: Also, note that "is equals or is after" is equivalent to "is not before"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not natively. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35300229/628318
which gives the "inclusive" example of:

```
containsNow = !now.isBefore( start ) && now.isBefore( stop );
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Interval` in [ThreeTen-Extra](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) for a task like this. (Assuming you are willing o pull in a library)

Answer (score 3):

My lib [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) offers [MomentInterval](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/MomentInterval.html) which is interoperable with the type `Instant` and also allows either half-open (default) or closed intervals. Example:

```
Instant start = ...;
Instant end = ...;

MomentInterval interval = MomentInterval.between(start, end); // half-open (end exclusive)
MomentInterval closed = interval.withClosedEnd(); // (inclusive)
```

Testing if an interval contains a test instant is easy, for example:

```
boolean isInRange = interval.contains(Moment.from(testInstant));
```

I agree that using an extra lib is probably overkill if you only want to do this simple in-range-test, but if you like to manipulate intervals or to do complex queries in interval trees then my lib might be interesting enough for you, see the other classes in the [range-package](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/package-summary.html).

Comment: I briefly looked at the library in the github. Seems very impressive

Comment: @MichaelGantman Thanks, by the way, I could also have mentioned the class `SimpleInterval<Instant>` because it always operates directly with `Instant`, however, it does not allow closed intervals what the OP wants, too (IMHO a little bit strange request for instants which have a time portion).

Comment: not the right forum for this, but I couldn't find your contact info. Please look me up on LinkedIn and connect, please. On my page I have some Date formatting related articles and an article about my own Open source lib. I would like to hear your opinion. After (and if) you connect I would delee this comment as it is not related to this question

Answer (score 2):

I realized thanks to @kumesana comment that the the range check can be simplified into a more readable form by taking advantage that `testSubject2.equals(start) || testSubject2.isAfter(start)` can be effectively replaced with `!testSubject2.isBefore(start)` so the inclusive range check can be implemented as:

```java
private boolean timestampInRange(Instant start, Instant end, Instant subject) {
   return !subject.isBefore(start) && !subject.isAfter(end);
}
```

Alternatively, I found that the [Joda Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library has [`org.joda.time.Interval`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) that allows for range checks via `.contains()` but that requires converting my `java.time.Instants` to `org.joda.time.Instant`, so the `ThreeTen-Extra` library from the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58730309/90580) seems more appropriate since it works with regular `java.time.Instant`.

Comment: That "other answer" is by the author of Joda Time, ThreeTen-Extra, and the java.time library, Stephen Colbourne, so it's about as authoritative an answer as it is possible to get!

Answer (score 1):

In JDK 8, no there is no such class. There are 2 classes that may provide partial support for your needs. It is [Period](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) and [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html)