# how to compare two date with my get date in android

Tags: android, android-date

In the below code, I want to compare a start date and an end date with my schedule date. I want to find within a week how many tasks are availables.

Suppose 16-03-2020 is the start date and 22-03-2020 the end date, my schedule date are like this 16 to 20. How many dates are there want to

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Log.v("Current Week", String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)));
int current_week = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
int week_start_day = calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek(); // this will get the starting day os week in integer format i-e 1 if monday
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Current Week is" + current_week + "Start Day is" + week_start_day, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
    .show();

// get the starting and ending date
// Set the calendar to sunday of the current week
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
System.out.println("Current week = " + Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

// Print dates of the current week starting on Sunday
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
String startDate = "", endDate = "";
startDate = df.format(calendar.getTime());
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);
endDate = df.format(calendar.getTime());
System.out.println("Start Date = " + startDate);
System.out.println("End Date = " + endDate);

if (startDate.compareTo(scheduleDate) < 0 && endDate.compareTo(scheduleDate) > 0) {
    listTask.add(taskModel);
    taskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

else if (name.equals("date_start")) {
                                scheduleDates = String.valueOf(values);
                                DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                                DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                                // String inputDateStr="2013-06-24";
                                Date date = null;
                                try {
                                    date = inputFormat.parse(scheduleDates);
                                    scheduleDate = outputFormat.format(date);
                                } catch (ParseException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
```

Comment: Is something the matter with your code since you are posting a question? If we’re to help, please specify precisely how observed behaviour differs from the expected. If you get any error message, please paste it into the question. *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.* From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: how do I check if a Date is within a certain range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494180/java-how-do-i-check-if-a-date-is-within-a-certain-range) I recommend [the thorough answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35300229/5772882).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your date into timestamp instead of string.

Then it is just a comparison between integers.

```
// set starting and ending date
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
long startDate = calendar.getTime().getTime();
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);
long endDate = calendar.getTime().getTime();

Log.d(TAG,"Start Date = " + startDate);
Log.d(TAG,"End Date = " + endDate);

long scheduleDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime();

if (startDate <= scheduleDate && endDate > scheduleDate) {
    listTask.add(taskModel);
    taskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Or you can use the Date comparison methods

```
// set starting and ending date
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
Date startDate = calendar.getTime();
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);
Date endDate = calendar.getTime();

Log.d(TAG,"Start Date = " + startDate);
Log.d(TAG,"End Date = " + endDate);

Date scheduleDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

if (startDate.before(scheduleDate) && endDate.after(scheduleDate)) {
    listTask.add(taskModel);
    taskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Timestamps for comparing dates? A funny idea IMHO. From your code I get *Type mismatch: cannot convert from Date to int* in the line `int startDate = calendar.getTime();`.

Comment: @Bruno both the codes i have tried in the first code was showing <= error.and second code showing before

Comment: @jyoabc, I've fixed my answer. Hope it finally help you

Comment: @Bruno see I adeed my scheduleDate is string