# Java: How to deal with cutoff timing for a system?

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-8

I have a scenario where a system remains **down** each day from 18:00 to next day 07:00 for all working days (in short, "Mon - Fri, 18:00 to 07:00"). That means, each week day system is going down at 18:00 and getting up at 07:00 next day morning. Outside this time range, system is down e.g. from Friday 18:00 till Monday 07:00. I need to store this time and match in my java application against **current time** to see if the above system is up or not.

Can you please suggest how should I proceed storing the system down timing (may be in a variable) and match against current time in my application to find out if system is down at current time or not? I need to do this using Java.

I tried multiple Java documentation for date and time, but couldn't get anything useful in this situation.

Comment: Looks like a scenario made for the use of `java.time`... What have you tried so far? Can you show us some code or ideas, at least?

Comment: You may be interested in this answer covering java.date/java.time API: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35300229/2519307

Comment: I have major blocker to store the range of system down time. If I would have given a single stop and start datetime, I could find if the current time is within that.

Comment: Monday to Friday, 18:00 until 07:00? Note that the last seven downtime hours of the week are actually on saturday.

Comment: @MCEmperor: That's correct. Thanks for thinking ahead and letting me to avoid accidentally including this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a class which is able to represent cutoff timings for systems (uptimes or downtimes).

The difficulty of the use case within the question is that the end time lies *before* the start time. That implies that the downtime starts at some day of the week, and ends *the next day* at a certain time.

So Monday until Friday, from 18:00 until 07:00, implies that the system is also down on Saturday, midnight until 7:00. If we want to handle this correctly, we need to take that into account.

Below the source code of the class. The constructor accepts a `Set` with the days of the week at which the cutoff times start, and the start and end times.

```java
public class Uptime {

    private final Set<DayOfWeek> daysOfUptimeStart;

    private final LocalTime startTime;

    private final LocalTime endTime;

    public Uptime(Set<DayOfWeek> daysOfUptimeStart, LocalTime startTime, LocalTime endTime) {
        this.daysOfUptimeStart = Collections.unmodifiableSet(daysOfUptimeStart);
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }

    public boolean isUp(LocalDateTime dateTime) {
        LocalTime time = dateTime.toLocalTime();
        if (!this.startTime.isAfter(this.endTime)) {
            return this.daysOfUptimeStart.contains(dateTime.getDayOfWeek()) && !time.isBefore(this.startTime) && !time.isAfter(this.endTime);
        }
        else {
            if (time.isBefore(this.startTime) && time.isAfter(this.endTime)) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return this.daysOfUptimeStart.contains(dateTime.getDayOfWeek().minus(!time.isBefore(this.startTime) ? 0 : 1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Test

In order to test this, I have generated some dates: all dates from 14 to 20 September 2020 (Monday to Sunday), combined with 4 AM, 8 AM, 1 PM, 5 PM, 7 PM and 11 PM.

The code prints the datetimes, along with whether the system is up or not. We expect that:

- on Monday, the system is down at 7 PM and 11 PM;
- on Tuesday until Friday, the system is down at 4 AM, 7 PM and 11 PM;
- on Saturday, the system is down at 4 AM.

```
// Static importing java.time.DayOfWeek.* here
Uptime uptime = new Uptime(Set.of(MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY), LocalTime.of(18, 0), LocalTime.of(7, 0));

YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of(2020, Month.SEPTEMBER);
List<LocalDateTime> datetimes = IntStream.rangeClosed(14, 20) // September 2020, MONDAY till SUNDAY
    .mapToObj(ym::atDay)
    .flatMap(date -> IntStream.of(4, 8, 13, 17, 19, 23)
        .mapToObj(hour -> LocalTime.of(hour, 0))
        .map(date::atTime))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

datetimes.forEach(datetime -> System.out.printf("%s %-12s %s\n", datetime, "(" + datetime.getDayOfWeek() + "):", !uptime.isUp(datetime)));
```

The output matches the expectation.

---

#### Update

A revision to the original post slightly changed the requirement. However,
**you don't have to modify abovementioned code**, as it'll still work if you modify *your input*. In fact, you are recording *up-times* instead of *down-times*. So instead, register your up-time times: Monday to Friday, 7:00 to 18:00.

```java
Set<DayOfWeek> daysOfWeek = Set.of(MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY);
LocalTime start = LocalTime.of(7, 0);
LocalTime end = LocalTime.of(18, 0);
Uptime uptime = new Uptime(daysOfWeek, start, end);
```

Now with `uptime.isUp(LocalDateTime.now())` you can still check whether the system is up.

Comment: Thanks for putting so much of efforts in writing down this code. This is very helpful. I appreciate that. This is working perfectly for week days scenarios, but during weekend, when system is down, it shows system is up...which I will modify the code and get this working as per my needs. Thanks again.

Comment: @Sonu That is because in your question (revision 1) you describe that downtimes only occur from Monday until Friday — which means that on Saturdays and Sundays, the system would not be down. However, **the code need not to be changed**, just modify your input. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks @MC Emperor. Yes, that's why edited the question to explicitly mention it. But thanks a lot, your code is awesome. It gave me a lot of understanding in dealing with such scenarios. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like:

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Tests
        showServerStatus(List.of(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY, DayOfWeek.SUNDAY), LocalTime.of(7, 0), LocalTime.of(18, 0));
        showServerStatus(List.of(DayOfWeek.THURSDAY, DayOfWeek.SATURDAY), LocalTime.of(6, 0), LocalTime.of(20, 0));
    }

    static void showServerStatus(List<DayOfWeek> offDays, LocalTime startTime, LocalTime endTime) {
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        if (!offDays.contains(now.getDayOfWeek()) && !now.toLocalTime().isBefore(startTime)
                && !now.toLocalTime().isAfter(endTime)) {
            System.out.println("The server should be up now.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The server should be down now.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output for me now:**

```
The server should be up now.
The server should be down now.
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: Thanks for your putting efforts and writing this piece of code. That's helpful. But let's say, going forward, I get multiple such systems which have their own cutoff timings, I should not add conditions for all those. I am looking for a generic solution where lets say, "system A is down for Mon-Sat, 20:00 to 06:00, will I be able to proceed and send request to this". I would like to know how can I make aware my java program about this range in generic way.

Comment: @Sonu - I've updated the answer to make it generic.