# Java HashMap filter between two dates

Tags: java, datetime, hashmap

I'm trying to filter or limit between two dates (Locale Date), and I'm not sure how to do it in the code below.

**My Code**

```
        Map<String, Double> Total_IExpense = datatransaction.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(TransactionData::getName,
                        Collectors.summingDouble(TransactionData::getAmount)));
```

```
Date        Name    Amount

04-Jan-21   Jomon   3,900.00
01-Jan-21   John    650.00
29-Dec-20   Priya   1,435.00
28-Dec-20   Jore    303.00
28-Dec-20   Jomon   453.74
28-Dec-20   Jore    81.67
26-Dec-20   John    25.12
21-Nov-20   Priya   118.38
21-Nov-20   Jomon   21.31
20-Nov-20   John    438.24
20-Nov-20   John    78.88
19-Nov-20   Jai 1,612.81
19-Nov-20   Priya   68.22
```

I required to filter - 21-Nov-20 to 28-Dec-20 and expected output

```
Date        Name    Amount
21-Nov-20   Jomon   21.31
21-Nov-20   Priya   118.38
26-Dec-20   John    25.12
28-Dec-20   Jomon   453.74
28-Dec-20   Jore    384.67
```

Comment: where does the `Date` come from your model ? I only see a `String` and `Doubles`.  Btw if you find a way to manipulate a Date, you can filter your stream using prebuilt comparaison function from LocalDate objetcs

Comment: a `LocalDate` (assuming that is meant by "Locale Date") has methods `isAfter()` and `isBefore()` that can be user in a `filter(...)` in your `Stream`. (if still using the ancient `java.util.Date` class, it has `after()` and `before()`)

Comment: I am unsure what is stopping you. Does this answer your question? [Java: how do I check if a Date is within a certain range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494180/java-how-do-i-check-if-a-date-is-within-a-certain-range)

Comment: Do you want grouping by *date **and** name*? It seems to me the two rows `28-Dec-20   Jore    303.00` and `28-Dec-20   Jore    81.67` have been summed into `28-Dec-20   Jore    384.67` in your required/expected output whereas the two rows with name `Jomon` have not been added together.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group by multiple field names in java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28342814/group-by-multiple-field-names-in-java-8)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should filter a stream based on a **predicate** (condition) provided as an argument with the **filter()** method.

In case you need to filter a string stream and only return strings starting with ’n’

```
strFlux.filter(s->s.startsWith("n")).log();
```

if length of a string is greater than 4, then return it’s length as an element of the stream.

```
strFlux.filter(s -> s.length() > 4).map(s->s.length()).log(); //Now it will be a Flux<Integer>
```